# Unable to Click the a href value (<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.lnkAdd">New Grade</a>)

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, nunit, selenium-webdriver, testng

this is for my a html code

```
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed;">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td style="line-height: 30px;"> 
 No. of records: <span data-bind="text: ActiveGrade().length">12</span>&nbsp;|
 <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.lnkAdd">New Grade</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

when we get the xpath for the above href location and add the click method , but during the Execution its not clickable

my Xpath:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='GradeListView1']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a")

public WebElement new_grade

new_grade.click()
```

I want to click the "New Grade" Hyperlink (during the click its open an new popup wndow)

thanks

ptabu

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(.,'New Grade')]");
```

And into your html, instead of using the `data-bind`, did you try do use the `onClick` ?

```
<a href="#" onClick="$root.lnkAdd">New Grade</a>
```

Comment: above code also not executed still its not clickable during the execution, also i used the GetText method, but not solved my problem

Comment: can you show your rendering in html ? Do you really catch the element ?

Comment: <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 30px;">
No. of records:
<span data-bind="text: ActiveGrade().length">12</span>
 |
<a data-bind="click: $root.lnkAdd" href="#">New Grade</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: my java code in eclipse WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(.,'New Grade')]"));
link.click();

Comment: you are on firefox ? if yes, try comething else

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve it,

1. Change your xpath to `//a[text()='New Grade']` or
2. Find your link by, `By.linktext("//a[text()='New Grade']")`

Give them a try, they must work for you.

Comment: Sorry still i'm not able to click that hyperlink, this is for designed with MVC Arch (.net), this is for my first project(testing) with MVC

Comment: <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.lnkAdd">New Grade</a>, in that View Model (MVC) they have to call the function lnkadd

Comment: I have no idea about 'data-bind'. You should speak to ur developers and know how to handle it.